# How to set loader when component render first time Nuxt 3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vue-component, nuxtjs3

I am working on nuxt 3 project using the element plus library and one of my pages have 3 tabs and I have divided 3 tabs content into 3 component and I have set conditions to render only the first tab component initially. When clicking on the 2nd or 3rd tab then specific tabs components will be rendered.

My issue is when I click on the 2nd or 3rd tab the very first time at the time page is taking a bit of time to load the component (not much but we can see the difference)

After, once all 3 components have loaded then each tab's content load smoothly without taking time.

```js
<template>
<el-tabs v-model="activeTabName" @tab-click="handleClick">
  <el-tab-pane label="Tab 1" name="tab1">
    <LazyTab1
      v-if="activeTabName == 'tab1'"
      :form-data="formData"
      :loader="loader"
      @on-submit="submitForm"
    />
  </el-tab-pane>
  <el-tab-pane label="Tab 2" name="tab2">
    <LazyTab2
      v-if="activeTabName == 'tab2'"
      :form-data="formData"
      :loader="loader"
      @submit-form="submitForm"
    />
  </el-tab-pane>
  <el-tab-pane label="Tab 3" name="tab3">
    <LazyTab3
      v-if="activeTabName == 'tab3'"
      :form-data="formData"
      :loader="loader"
      @on-submit="submitForm"
    />
  </el-tab-pane>
</el-tabs>
</template>

<script setup>
const activeTabName = ref("tab1");
const formData = reactive({
  tab1: {
    ..
    ..
  },
  tab2: {
    ..
    ..
  },
  tab2: {
    ..
    ..
  }
});

//Tab click event
const handleClick = (tab, event) => {
};

//Form submit
const submitForm = async (formRef) => {
  //After form submit code
}

//Get form details
const getDetails = async () => {
  //API call and set the formData from API response
}
onMounted(() => {
  getDetails();
});
</script>
```

I have set the `if` condition on each tab so it load only one at a time (current tab) but when we switch the tab initially then the issue occurred on the first time only after loaded it works perfectly.

Please help me with a way to fix this. Also, let me know if there is a need for anything else apart from the above.

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: @everyone please help me on this!

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, nuxt tries to process the request on the server side while the DOM is not loaded on the client, but for some reason it cannot do so. To explicitly indicate that the function should be executed after mounting the DOM on the client, use `nextTick()`

```js
onMounted(async () => {
  await nextTick();
  getDetails();
});
```

as stated in the documentation - https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/directory-structure/components#client-components

> .client components are rendered only after being mounted. To access
> the rendered template using onMounted(), add await nextTick() in the
> callback of the onMounted() hook.

more about nextTick - https://vuejs.org/api/general.html#nexttick